# How to change the text color in a TextView in Android?

Tags: android, colors, textview

So i am trying to make a code which will change the color of the text in a textView
I declared the color in the XML as this:

```
<color name="right">#FF00FF00</color>
```

However, when I try to change the color of the TextView score, in the following:

```
if(input.equalsIgnoreCase(answer+"")){
        numRight++;
        score.setTextColor(R.color.right);
        correct="Correct!";
    }
```

The text just dissapears.  Am I referencing the color wrong?  why doesnt this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are referencing it incorrectly:

score.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.right);

Comment: oh wow thanks.  That worked.  Do you need to do that with all values (like dimensions and strings)

Answer (score 1):

I hope it will work properly.

```
textView1.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.all));
```

all is name which is pertaining to color define in xml file like that.

```
<color name= "all">#ffffff</color>
```

you can use also below format it is working properly for me.

```
textView1.setTextColor(0xff000000);
```